# How can I aim farther using the keyboard controls in DoomRL?

Tags: doomrl

When firing a weapon in [DoomRL](http://doom.chaosforge.org/), you can aim using either the arrow keys or the mouse. When using the keyboard, DoomRL allows me to aim up to 8 tiles away. When using the mouse, I can aim as far as I'd like. This is useful for tactics like blind-firing at a tile out of your vision range, but I prefer to use the keyboard controls. Is there a way to aim at a specific distant tile using the keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug with the differences between the G-version and the normal version -- you can't aim further in ASCII mode. It may be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://doom.chaosforge.org/wiki/Manual:keybindings.lua the "L" key lets you "Look around", or "Use the Move commands to move the cursor in order to look. Use the Cancel command to stop looking.".  It sounds like you would be able to use this to accomplish what you want.

Comment: When Looking with the L key, I can examine any square as far as I'd like, but there doesn't seem to be a way to fire in this mode.